# Could not find an object named 'Notification__e'. Trailhead challenge

Tags: apex, trailhead

I am doing Trailhead from the link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-platform-events/steps/platform-event-define and getting the below error.

[image]

Here I have created everything is right.

[image]

Comment: make sure your trailhead is pointing towards the right org.

Comment: glls - You're right.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common mistake when you have multiple orgs that you forget to switch accounts for validating a challenge.

[image]

make sure that you have completed the challenge in the selected org, or switch to the one you completed it in to validate.